# Empty POST requests from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, post, express

I have two apps in NodeJS. One process some data, the second one sends a POST request with a file attached to a ExpressJS app. Everything works ok, but I have one strange situation. The app that receives the request will have strange logs after getting and processing the POST request:

`14:23:07 web.1  | POST / - - ms - -
14:23:09 web.1  | POST / - - ms - -
14:23:11 web.1  | POST / - - ms - -
14:23:12 web.1  | POST / - - ms - -
14:23:14 web.1  | POST / - - ms - -
14:23:15 web.1  | POST / - - ms - -`

If I make for example 10 requests, the app will receive them, process them, and after a while will start receiving this weird empty requests. And for example: 10 requests will produce 10 empty ones over time (not immediately).

If I kill the app that makes the POST request (sends the file) immediately after sending the last request (if we make 10 of them for example), the receiving app will be flooded with the remaining empty request.

Any idea what is causing this?

## Tech Specs

**Posting App**

- NodeJS 4.1.1
- Form-data module for making the POST request
- Code for making the POST

  function webhook(url, referenceId, stream) {
      var form = new FormData();
      form.append('referenceId', referenceId);
      form.append('pdf', stream);

  ```
  form.submit(url, function(err, response) {
      console.log(response);
  });
  ```

  }

**Reciving App**

- NodeJS: 4.1.1
- ExpressJS: 4.13.1
- Multer module for handling file in POST request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when you don't respond with a status message. Adding

```
res.status(200).end();
```

after you process the request, will display the right logs in your receiving app.